# How to do a picture lookup using Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I am wondering if there is a solution to load a picture using formula (not VBA) from a list of pictures in Excel

For example,

```
=IF(TODAY()-B9<8,G6,"puste")
```

Let's say I have a picture in cell `G6`, that I want the formula to return if the condition is true.

[image]

Comment: [This](https://trumpexcel.com/picture-lookup/) might be of help.

Comment: @BigBen okay, this works but.. :)
it is connected with one cell only, I am using a range as a template and these $$ bothers me a lot as i copy/paste this range multiple times and in another sheet is not working - template: https://imgur.com/a/d1xgyJn
tab where template is pasted:https://imgur.com/a/fPLZJis

Comment: you can make the range reference relative by removing the $ signs as needed @Cactooos

Comment: @ScottHoltzman not really, excel doesnt let me to delete these - in paralel i was working on conditional formatting instead of picture (if i cant make it) and for the same problem of undeletable $ this worked: Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats, Operation _
        :=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    wonder if it might work for moving template with pictures as well

Answer (score 1):

In brief, the solution can be summarized in 2 steps:

1. Create a linked picture cell using PasteSpecial method of Excel.
2. Modify the formula of linked cell to "Named Range" formula for making it dynamic.
3. (Optional) - If there are many cells, and one find it tiresome to manually change the address of each linked image then use the below VBA macro to assign Named Range formula to all cells.

---

```
Sub Set_Formula_Linked_Cell()

Dim rngDest As Range
Dim objPic As Object

    For Each rngDest In Range("F5:O18").Cells
        rngDest.Select
        Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste(Link:=True)
        objPic.Formula = "=Country_Flag"
        Set objPic = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

---

In Detail, let's follow through a similar situation:

1. Let's assume we have a list of Country and their adjacent flags.

[image: Country Flag List Table]

2. Next step is to copy the Cell (any cell which contain the flag, do not copy picture but the Cell/Range) and paste as Linked Picture in the destination cell.

[image: Create a linked Cell to the original image]

3. Now, a careful observation in the address bar reveals that current cell which displays a flag is linked to another cell. We need to change this formula. Unfortunately, we cannot change the formula here. Either it could be a direct reference or a named range but not a formula.

[image: Change the formula]

4. We will create a "Named Range" with the name "Country_Flag" and Formula as:

> =INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6,MATCH(Sheet1!$F$3,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,0))

[image: Create Name Range]

5. In the last Step, we will assign this named range to the linked cell.

[image: Assign Named Range to Linked Cell]

Comment: Hey, thanks, as mentioned I managed to do it thanks to the link from previous comment, however the problem is am using these cells as a template that is copied multiple times, then it doesnt work because i cannot delete $ in formulas

Comment: Write a short VBA code to replace $ or assign formula to linked cells. Need to run it once and then you can delete the VBA code to keep Excel macro-free, if you wish.

Comment: @jainaashish I also see you changed the problem to more general, in my case it is only one picture and one test (I am checking how many days is from now to date in a G6 cell, the number 'moves' the picture right - if 8 picture is in a2, if 7 in c2 and so on) there wont be more, and I think the way how you presented just complicate it instead of making easier

Comment: You need to take reference from solution, no one on this platform is going to do the project work for you.